# when will Lubuntu 14 final launch

Tags: lubuntu, beta

I am using Lubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14 Beta is already out.
I want to use Lubuntu 14, when will Lubuntu 14 final launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

April 17th 2014. Lubuntu is on the same release schedule as ubuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule

Any changes or delays would be announced at least on their blog or irc if not to the community in general.

See http://lubuntu.net/tags/lubuntu-release